# Strugging to send email to my gmail account

Tags: networking, email, gmail, postfix

I have a home mail server for receiving mail.  However if I send mail I have to send through a VM in the cloud because it has a non blocked static ip address

I have a gmail account which I have been trying to work out how to send email to.  I've had 20 tries at altering the server in the cloud and my domains and every time google has failed the email. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Im my home domain I have an txt record like this (the only spf record)

`v=spf1 ipv4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:_spf.google.com ~all`

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the ip address in the cloud

At my cloud server I am running postfix and my main.cf file has

`smtp_address_preference=ipv4`

which was a recommendation picked up here as the VM has both ip4 and ip6 capability

With this exact setup I get the following reply from google

```
<yyyyy@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[66.102.1.27]
    said: 550-5.7.26 The MAIL FROM domain [myhome.example.com] has an SPF
    record with a 550-5.7.26 hard fail policy (-all) but it fails to pass SPF
    checks with the ip: 550-5.7.26 [xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx]. To best protect our users
    from spam and phishing, 550-5.7.26 the message has been blocked. Please
    visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. w1-20020a5d6801000000b00325a5104cf4si2659832wru.974 -
    gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

I can't see what is wrong. Can someone help me please?

Comment: 0) Why are you including Google's SPF record if you are not sending _from_ Google servers using this sender domain? 1) Is `myhome.example.com` actually where you have the SPF record, or do you have it elsewhere (e.g. at the base `example.com`)? 2) Your shown SPF record has `~all` but the Gmail error message says it has found a hardfail `-all` instead; is that something you had before? 3) What is the TTL of the SPF record in your DNS? When you're making changes, do you wait for the previous TTL to expire before testing again?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I include it because google told me to (at least I thought they did). I did have `-all` before but changed it a long while back (I thought it was my missreading the font on my email client.  The spf records are hosted at my domain name provider, they are for `example.com` but my email address is `alan@example.com` the `mx` are `mail.example.com` but with different values of `example.com` for my home and my cloud server.  I just tried again TTL has expired, but google was detecting changes to my records almost instantly

Comment: Is it `example.com` or is it `myhome.example.com`?

Comment: Have you properly configured SPF, DKIM, and DMARC? It appears SPF isn’t configured properly